# Ошибка Frame for “View” will be different at run time

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift3

Вылезла ошибка, обновление фреймов не делает, так и остается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже что у Вас конфликт constraints. Вам необходимо найти этот конфликт или же удалить все constraints и добавить их заново.

```
Editor -> Resolve Auto-Layout Issues -> Clear all constraints in ** view controller
```